# Regex to stop matching if the string is not present

Tags: php, regex, go, match

I have a text with different paragraphs. In each paragraph i want to match a specific word, but in some of these this word is missing. How can i use the same regex to match if the word is detected, else continue.

As you can see i have to match the code  next to IhreArtikel-Nr. as you can see at line 9., but if the IhreArtikel-Nr. is not present the regex continue to match as you can see at line 7. and ruin line 8. too. How cand i do not match if the IhreArtikel is not there.

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDJau.png)

my regex:

```
\r?\n(\d{1,3})(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,25}\s\d{1,6})(?:\s\d{1,6}\w{1,10}\s)(\d{1,6})(\w{1,6})\s(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})\s(\d{1,4}\,\d{1,4}(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\/))(?:.*?)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}\,\d{1,2}\r?\n|\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3}\r?\n|\d{1,4}\r?\n)(.*?)(?(?=(?:IhreArtikel-Nr\.))(.*?)\r?\n|(.*?)\r?\n)
```

the text:

```
6 UR1040HRA735-765 60 10kg 600kg 28.09.2021 4,12EUR/kg 2,00 2.422,56
EFDEDUR-LackfarbelichtgrauRAL7035
SG,MV5:1HU0001/HU0032
IhreArtikel-Nr.:LAD7035-765
Zolltarifnummer:32082090
Ursprungsland:Deutschland

7 UR1040HG3081-765 60 10kg 600kg 28.09.2021 3,82EUR/kg 2,00 2.246,16
EFDEDUR-LackfarbeRAL9003
SignalweißSG,MV5:1HU0001/HU0032
Zolltarifnummer:32082090
Ursprungsland:Deutschland

8 UR1040HRA907-762 60 5kg 300kg 28.09.2021 5,25EUR/kg 2,00 1.543,50
EFDEDUR-Metalleffektlack
graualuminiumRAL9007SM,MV5:1
HU0001
IhreArtikel-Nr.:LAD9007
Zolltarifnummer:32082090
Ursprungsland:Deutschland

9 KP1516HRA735-742 32 25kg 800kg 28.09.2021 3,56EUR/kg 2,00 2.791,04
FREIOPLAST-LackfarbelichtgrauRAL
7035SG
IhreArtikel-Nr.:LAK7035
Zolltarifnummer:32082090
Ursprungsland:Deutschland
```

Comment: "As you can see" no we can't.  Paste the code as text into the question using a code block. Thanks

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDJau.png

Comment: If you needed _just_ the article numbers, this should be fairly easy. But then your regex so far probably wouldn't be this complex already, I suppose. But a _proper_ explanation of what else you need, is missing so far.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I need only to match the article numbers only where the Ihre Artikel text is present else to do nothing

Comment: Sorry, but why not `IhreArtikel-Nr\.:\K\w+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wr5mDM/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wahou, great thanks for letting me learn the `\K` to reset the starting point of the match! I would have used a positive lookbehind.

Comment: Because the paragraph number 7. do not have IhreArtikel-Nr\. and the rest of the regex will stop matching for nest paragraphs.

Comment: In this case put some logic in your program to loop over each paragraph and check if it contains the article number. If you don't get any match then you can handle it and iterate to the next paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if it's what you want, but maybe this regex helps:

```
^(\d{1,3})(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,25}\s\d{1,6})(?:\s\d{1,6}\w{1,10}\s)(\d{1,6})(\w{1,6})\s(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})\s(\d{1,4}\,\d{1,4}(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\/))(?:[^\n]*?)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,4}\,\d{1,2}|\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3}|\d{1,4})\n(?:^\S[^\n]*?\n)*?IhreArtikel-Nr\.
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/LzTiQ2/1)

Comment: Giving an answer without explaining what you did, and why, is like pushing a student out of plane without telling how the parachute works.